# WordPress - force body class to use the latest template name

Tags: wordpress

When using a page template, WordPress creates body classes associated with that page template.

In page template file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: My Template
 */
```

In body class:

```
<body class="... page-template-my-template ...
```

However, when changing the `Template Name` in the template file, and then updating the corresponding page to use this new template, and also updating the URL of that page, the body class is still using the **old** template name.
In body class:

```
<body class="... page-template-my-old-template-name ...
```

How can I force the body class to use the latest template name?

Comment: or append with JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the body_class method to output the right class, I needed to change the file name of the template file (not just the `Template Name` comment), and then reset the template attribute on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use function in body `<?php body_class(); >` to show classes in body.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```